# Customize list bullets in orgmode (emacs)

Tags: org-mode

I was actually looking for how to add other symbols besides -, +, 1., and so on. Has this been addressed somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want new symbols, or just to change the way they look? You might look at org-bullets:  https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets if all you want to change the way they look.

Comment: I have that package, I wanted to do the same with lists (not headings).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is not possible, at least in recent org-mode (> 9.0): the bullets are hardwired into the `org-list-full-item-re` regular expression. In other words, they are syntactic elements that help the parser recognize a list - they cannot be arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you, now I know this can't be done. However, with org-bullets is possible to do this with headings, so I wonder how these are not so hard-wired into the system...

Comment: I believe (I may be wrong) that org-bullets user overlays: it changes the appearance of the document but leaves the actual document unchanged.

Comment: A similar approach could be used for the bullets in listings, right?

Comment: I believe so: it's only a small matter of programming :-)